# How to check multiple selectors to trigger an event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

New to jquery but I am working on a responsive calendar. Now I have a start date and an end date field. If the end date is populated, the reoccurrence check box shows as it removes it from the not-visible class.

How can I add a check on the start date also? I want the check box to show when both of the start and end fields are filled not just one.

```js
 $("#end_date").on("input", function (){
            if($('#end_date').length >= 1) {
                $("#reoccurrence").removeClass('not-visible');
            } else {
                $("#reoccurrence").addClass('not-visible');
            }
        });
```

```css
.not-visible {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <div class="md-form md-form-container-fix">
    <input type="text" id="start_date" class="form-control date-picker" name="start_date" required />
    <label for="start_date">Start Date</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <div class="md-form md-form-container-fix">
    <input type="text" id="end_date" class="form-control date-picker" name="end_date" required />
    <label for="end_date">End Date</label>
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="form-check not-visible" id="reoccurrence" name="reoccurrence">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="is_reoccurring" name="is_reoccurring" value="1" />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="is_reoccurring"> Reoccurrence? </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, using [`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) will tell you whether that input exists in the DOM (0 = doesn't exist, 1 = exists), but it won't evaluate the values of the inputs.

> *length*
> The number of elements in the jQuery object.
> The number of elements currently matched.

Instead, I recommend using [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) to verify that the values of both inputs are not empty strings.

In the demonstration below, I define each input and the "reoccurrence" element as variables. I use [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) to combine the two inputs and bind the event handler to both. Alternatively, you could simply select both inputs: `$("#start_date,#end_date")`; see [multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Upon input, I define a boolean "oneEmpty" variable based on the values of both inputs. Then, I use [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to "add or remove one or more classes ... depending on ... the value of the state argument."

When either input is empty, the "oneEmpty" state is `true` and the "not-visible" class is toggled on. When both inputs are filled, the state is `false` and the class is toggled off.

```js
var $start_date = $('#start_date');
var $end_date = $('#end_date');
var $reoccurrence = $("#reoccurrence");

$start_date.add($end_date).on("input", function() {
  let oneEmpty = $start_date.val() == '' || $end_date.val() == '';
  $reoccurrence.toggleClass('not-visible', oneEmpty);
});
```

```css
.not-visible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <div class="md-form md-form-container-fix">
    <input type="text" id="start_date" class="form-control date-picker" name="start_date" required />
    <label for="start_date">Start Date</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <div class="md-form md-form-container-fix">
    <input type="text" id="end_date" class="form-control date-picker" name="end_date" required />
    <label for="end_date">End Date</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-check not-visible" id="reoccurrence" name="reoccurrence">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="is_reoccurring" name="is_reoccurring" value="1" />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="is_reoccurring"> Reoccurrence? </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks!